# Static IP in Sony Camera Remote API

Tags: camera, sony

I'm planning to integrate the Sony Camera Remote API to use with an Action Cam Mini AZ1. Before doing that, I have serious doubts about the possibility of connecting the camera to a static IP, instead of working in the same Wifi network.

Does anyone knows if that is possible?

Thanks!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Sorry connecting to a static IP is not possible.